# Search an NSMutableArray with strings if string is equal to other string NLog position of item

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with items in it.
I would like to compare every item with a string.
If the string is the same then the next item of the array should be stored in another array.

```
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Period:"];

// Filtern nach Periode 
NSMutableArray *Eventarray =[NSMutableArray array];


for(int i=0;i<[lines count]; i++)
{

    NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[lines objectAtIndex:i]description]];
    //  NSLog(@"%@",string1);


    int index = [[lines objectAtIndex:i] indexOfObject:@"Period:"];
     NSLog(@"%@",index);

    if ([[lines objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Period:"]) 
    {
        //strings are same

        NSLog(@"ii");

           NSLog(@"ii");
        int e=i+1;
        NSMutableString *Periode = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[lines objectAtIndex:e]];

        [Eventarray addObject:Periode];
    }

    [string1 deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([string1 length]-1, 1)];

}

for(int i=0;i<[Eventarray count]; i++)
{
      NSLog(@"Eventarray: %@", [Eventarray objectAtIndex:i]);

}
```

The array looks like this:

```
2013-08-12 13:31:35.375 xxxx[3809:207] PublishedRoster
2013-08-12 13:31:35.376 xxxx[3809:207] Period:
2013-08-12 13:31:35.377 xxxx[3809:207] 25Jul2013-08Sep2013
```

I tried everything but I don't know whats wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: BOOL isTheObjectThere = [myArray containsObject:@"my string"]; 
if bool return yes then add that string into second array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSRange`

If you want to search for a substring

```
NSString *homebrew = @"Rajneesh071";
NSRange range = [homebrew rangeOfString:@"Raj"];

// Did we find the string "Raj" ?
if (range.length > 0)
  NSLog(@"Range is: %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
```

In your code you can do it like.

```
for(int i=0;i<[lines count]; i++)
{
    NSRange stringRange = [[lines objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:@"Period:" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [Eventarray addObject:Periode];
    }
}
```